# How to insert data into a temporary table using an existing table and new columns

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to insert data into a temporary table within my stored procedure. The data is selected from an existing table and creating new columns with concatenated data. I'm getting an error that the column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. I'm pretty certain that the code in my application is correct so I believe the issue is with the way I'm storing the data in a temporary table.

Here is my proc:

```
AS
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
( 
    [ID] [varchar](10),
    [FIRST_NAME] varchar(50),
    [LAST_NAME] varchar(50),
    [WEBSITE_LINK] varchar(200)
)

INSERT INTO #TempTable

    SELECT USER.ID,USER.FIRSTNAME AS [FIRST_NAME], USER.LASTNAME AS 
[LAST_NAME]
    FROM USER   
    WHERE USER.Registered = 'Yes'

    DECLARE @Link1 NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @Link2 VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @Link3 NVARCHAR(4)

    SET @Link1 = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/user/'
    SET @Link2 = (SELECT USER.ID FROM USER WHERE USER.Registered = 
'Yes')
    SET @Link3 ='/document.doc'
    SET @WEBSITE_LINK = (SELECT concat(@Link1,@Link2,@Link3 )AS 
[WEBSITE_LINK]) 

DROP TABLE #TempTable
END
```

Comment: Your temp table has 4 columns and your select to insert into the temp table only has 3 columns AND you aren't specifying which columns to insert which tells SQL Server you are inserting ALL columns. Change `INSERT INTO #TempTable` to `INSERT INTO #TempTable(ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)` to solve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is your problem:

```
SET @Link2 = (SELECT USER.ID FROM USER WHERE USER.Registered = 'Yes')
```

What if there are six of them? A single variable can't hold all of them. You can do:

```
SELECT TOP(1) @Link2 = USER.ID FROM USER WHERE USER.Registered = 'Yes' ORDER BY [SOMETHING];
```

If the goal is to create a temp table with a full [WEBSITE_LINK], you can do that without all those variables:

```
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #TempTable
    ( 
        [ID] [varchar](10),
        [FIRST_NAME] varchar(50),
        [LAST_NAME] varchar(50),
        [WEBSITE_LINK] varchar(200)
    )

    INSERT INTO #TempTable
        SELECT DISTINCT u.ID
            , [FIRST_NAME] = u.FIRSTNAME
            , [LAST_NAME] = u.LASTNAME
            , [WEBSITE_LINK] = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/user/' + 
                CAST(u.ID AS VARCHAR(10)) + 
                '/document.doc'
        FROM [USER] u   
        WHERE u.Registered = 'Yes'

    -- Do something with these values...

    DROP TABLE #TempTable
END
```

Comment: I believe you're correct. The problem is I need to access the USER.ID column from the first select statement and get rid of the second SELECT statement all together. I've tried to use SELECT USER.ID AS [ID] and then change the line Set @Link2 = [ID] but that doesn't work because I can't seem to access the [ID] clause.

Comment: I'm not sure what your code is trying to do, but I'll put an edit above with my best guess...